# Does a control panel that will start/stop two pumps require its own circuit protection?

Tags: power, power-engineering, circuit-breaker, fluid-pump

Does a control panel used to start/stop two pumps require circuit protection for the main 208V feeder lines if those lines are already protected at the main panel in a separate room?

The main panel has the correct sized breakers for each pump. These breakers then feed into the control panel in a different room which has the contactors to start/stop the pumps.

Comment: I think this is a question for regulatory authorities. It's not really an electrical engineering question. I prefer to have a panel shut-off for panels in separate locations. If for no other reason, so that I can work on the panel subsections, conveniently. I have a similar situation -- a set of breakers in a main panel which are assigned to support a specific subpanel at a different location. The subpanel has its own disconnect, though, both outside the structure as well as inside on the panel itself. But whether or not that's required by regulation is an entirely different question.

Comment: @periblepsis it's certainly an electrical engineering question. Your concern is whether this site covers only small electronics, or also big ones as well. All the [mentioned topics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are small electronics but it doesn't say big ones aren't allowed, either

Comment: There's a [tag:power-engineering] tag so I suppose it is on-topic. I added the power-engineering tag, and since there's a maximum of 5 tags, removed "control" and "panel" as they didn't seem particularly useful

Answer (score 0):

Power for the control panel and contactor coils must come from *somewhere*.

That must be approved equipment (e.g. UL Listed) and it must be on an appropriately sized (protected) circuit according to its labeling and instructions.

Some control equipment is designed and approved to share a circuit with very large equipment, specifically to avoid the dumbness of having to run another circuit just for that.  Take an EV wall charge unit that might take 5 watts for the GFCI, square wave generator and smug LEDs, but sits on a 60A or 100A circuit also feeding the EV charger (which is onboard the car).

Since it is controlling the pumps via contactors, the power source for the contactor coils can be separate from the pumps themselves.  For instance a typical American 240V installed A/C unit with obsolete "bang-bang" controls typically has a contactor with 24V coil, and that comes from a transformer on the furnace/air handler's 120V supply.  This can be a little bit of a shock to someone who thought they fully de-energized the A/C unit when they cut its 240V breaker.  Sometimes the control panel is able to power itself from such control voltage, such as a typical American thermostat running on that same 24V.

Answer (score 0):

> Does a control panel used to start/stop two pumps require circuit protection for the main 208V feeder lines if those lines are already protected at the main panel in a separate room?

No.

However, for safety reasons and convenience, two isolators are to be provided in the control panel.

[image]

The isolators resemble MCBs.